# Solr schema "Already closed" and related errors after base DSE/Solr Node setup

Tags: datastax

Getting started with DSE Solr nodes, initial setup fine and was able to follow this example with no issues:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchTutStrt.html

My first test use case is some example location data, modifying the tutorial example.  I am now at a state where I can create my table, insert ~5K example rows, and when pushing the schema get the following exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <response>
    <lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">245</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Already closed</str><str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Already closed
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.&lt;init&gt;(SolrCore.java:851)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraCoreContainer.doReload(CassandraCoreContainer.java:700)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraCoreContainer.create(CassandraCoreContainer.java:224)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.SolrCoreResourceManager.createCore(SolrCoreResourceManager.java:256)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.admin.CassandraCoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CassandraCoreAdminHandler.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:152)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:137)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:669)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:248)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.servlet.CassandraDispatchFilter.doFilter(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.audit.SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.doFilter(SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.CassandraAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(CassandraAuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.DseAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DseAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:891)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:750)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:2283)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: Already closed
        at org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory.get(CachingDirectoryFactory.java:340)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getNewIndexDir(SolrCore.java:262)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:480)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:772)
        ... 33 more
    500name=snet_data.location_test1&action=CREATE

Using this as my table create statement:

```
CREATE table location_test1 (
"id" TIMEUUID,
"source_id" UUID,
"name" VARCHAR,
"address" VARCHAR,
"address_extended" VARCHAR,
"po_box" VARCHAR,
"locality" VARCHAR,
"region" VARCHAR,
"post_town" VARCHAR,
"admin_region" VARCHAR,
"postcode" VARCHAR,
"country" VARCHAR,
"tel" VARCHAR,
"latlon" VARCHAR,
"neighborhood" SET<VARCHAR>,
"website" VARCHAR,
"email" VARCHAR,
"category_ids" SET<VARCHAR>,
"status" VARCHAR,
"chain_name" VARCHAR,
"chain_id" UUID,
PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
```

With the solr schema:

```
<schema name="location_test1" version="1.5">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="geo" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>
  <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField"/>
  <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField"/>
 </types>
 <fields>
   <field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true"  stored="true" docValues="true"/>
   <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <field name="latlon" type="geo" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
</fields>
<defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField>
<uniqueKey>(id)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

UPDATED (10/29) after new tests

So after seeming like these errors are being caused b/c DSE Solr is in some bad state, even after dropping table and data and starting over, I decided to drop the entire keyspace as the restart point.  Getting different behavior now.., consistent with earlier errors where on core creation it complains that a multi-value field should be mapped to List/Set type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">325</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Unable to create core: snet_data.location_test1</str><str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: snet_data.location_test1
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.recordAndThrow(CoreContainer.java:957)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraCoreContainer.create(CassandraCoreContainer.java:266)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.SolrCoreResourceManager.createCore(SolrCoreResourceManager.java:256)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.admin.CassandraCoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CassandraCoreAdminHandler.java:117)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:152)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:669)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:248)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.servlet.CassandraDispatchFilter.doFilter(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.audit.SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.doFilter(SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.CassandraAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(CassandraAuthorizationFilter.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.DseAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DseAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:891)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:750)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:2283)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multi-valued field status should be mapped to either List or Set types, found: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.update(Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.java:115)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraCoreContainer.create(CassandraCoreContainer.java:245)
        ... 31 more
</str><int name="code">500</int></lst><str name="params">name=snet_data.location_test1&amp;action=CREATE</str>
</response>
```

Just like before with other field errors, the status field it's complaining about is defined in the table as a varchar, and in the schema as a string, so not quite sure why it complains about these.

What I have done now is stripped the schema down to just id,name,latlon.  Back to where I don't get the multi-value errors on single value varchar/string fields.., back to original "Already Closed" error

Here are my curl statements, built from example referenced above from datastax solr tutorial:

```
curl http://10.0.1.212:8983/solr/resource/snet_data.location_test1/solrconfig.xml --data-binary @solrconfig.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

curl http://10.0.1.212:8983/solr/resource/snet_data.location_test1/schema.xml --data-binary @schema.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

curl "http://10.0.1.212:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=snet_data.location_test1"
```

Steps Taken in running setup tests:

Log into cql shell and do following

Create keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE snet_data WITH REPLICATION =
       {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Solr':1};
```

Create table:

```
CREATE table location_test1 (
"id" TIMEUUID,
"source_id" UUID,
"name" VARCHAR,
"address" VARCHAR,
"address_extended" VARCHAR,
"po_box" VARCHAR,
"locality" VARCHAR,
"region" VARCHAR,
"post_town" VARCHAR,
"admin_region" VARCHAR,
"postcode" VARCHAR,
"country" VARCHAR,
"tel" VARCHAR,
"latlon" VARCHAR,
"neighborhood" SET<VARCHAR>,
"website" VARCHAR,
"email" VARCHAR,
"category_ids" SET<VARCHAR>,
"status" VARCHAR,
"chain_name" VARCHAR,
"chain_id" UUID,
PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
```

(tried both importing test of 5k records like tutorial, also running solr curl commands sans inserting initial data)

Run solr curl commands to setup config, schema, core:

```
curl http://10.0.1.212:8983/solr/resource/snet_data.location_test1/solrconfig.xml --data-binary @solrconfig.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

curl http://10.0.1.212:8983/solr/resource/snet_data.location_test1/schema.xml --data-binary @schema.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

curl "http://10.0.1.212:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=snet_data.location_test1"
```

Comment: Can you share your curl statements?

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step reproduction scenario, from DSE installation to error, and fix your Solr schema version to be 1.5.

Comment: updated schema to 1.5 (why is that required by the way?), updated post with steps at bottom I have been following

Comment: Solr's schema versions have evolved throughout releases and older ones won't support some features. You may as well be on 1.5 as that's the latest supported by DSE. More details: http://solr.pl/en/2010/08/16/what-is-schema-xml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your error after using your schema and create table statements. After crashing a few times trying to create the core the server finally gives that error, probably because it is in an inconsistent state.

If you use the following in your schema I guess all will be ok for you. I would need to know exact versions to be 100% sure though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="myTest" version="1.5">
```

To avoid future problems here is what I would recommend you:

- Look for the 'wiki' demo in the demos folder.
- Use that as a template. Change scripts' core names, change the schema, change the solrconfig, etc.
- This will be convenient as the scripts do the work for you, you have already working schemas etc you can modify and be sure they work

Hope it helps.

UPDATE 10/30:

I would need your exact version but you've made progress as at one point I did also get that 'status' multivalued field error. Let's go step by step:

- Stop the server and delete stuff. In my case: `rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/*`
- Start the server: `dse cassandra -s`
- Create the ks and table with the cqlsh shell:

  CREATE KEYSPACE wiki WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

  USE wiki;

  CREATE table location_test1 (
  "id" TIMEUUID,
  "source_id" UUID,
  "name" VARCHAR,
  "address" VARCHAR,
  "address_extended" VARCHAR,
  "po_box" VARCHAR,
  "locality" VARCHAR,
  "region" VARCHAR,
  "post_town" VARCHAR,
  "admin_region" VARCHAR,
  "postcode" VARCHAR,
  "country" VARCHAR,
  "tel" VARCHAR,
  "latlon" VARCHAR,
  "neighborhood" SET,
  "website" VARCHAR,
  "email" VARCHAR,
  "category_ids" SET,
  "status" VARCHAR,
  "chain_name" VARCHAR,
  "chain_id" UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
- Edit schema.xml and copy your own. I copied the one in your question. I use the solrconfig from the wiki demo.

curl http://:8983/solr/resource/wiki.location_test1/schema.xml --data-binary @schema.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

SUCCESS

```
curl http://<host>:8983/solr/resource/wiki.location_test1/solrconfig.xml --data-binary @solrconfig.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

SUCCESS

curl "http://<host>:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=wiki.location_test1"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1598</int></lst>
</response>
```

It should work. If it doesn't I need your exact versions. Sorry about the formatting, I can't get it to show as code...

Comment: Thanks for reply Bereng, I have this as my header in my schema: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><schema name="location_test1" version="0.2">`  I tried bumping the version and trying again from scratch, still same issue.  Will try starting from the wiki example instead of the nhanes_ks one from the DSE Solr getting started to see if that makes a difference

Comment: using the Wikipedia example from the dse-demos folder, get new error: `uniqueKey field (null) can not be configured to be multivalued`  Looks like only real difference between the Wikipedia example and the nhandes_ks example from the dse docs is the uniqueKey value in the Wikipedia example is "id" where the nhanes one is "(id)"

Comment: another test, with same outcome.  I started from scratch again, and used a stripped down schema with only the id and name fields, added back in the "(id)" as the uniqueKey, get same error as previous: `uniqueKey field (null) can not be configured to be multivalued`   would seem system is in some borked state again which is confusing.  DSE docs say that DSE Solr is managed by managing the keyspaces/tables..., so would assume when I drop and recreate to start from scratch things would just behave, if that's not the case how does one go through resetting up tables/indexes sans a re-install?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, when you drop your table it should wipe your solr core and creating it again will be the same as creating one from scratch

Comment: Awesome.., thanks for test and example Bereng.  Turns out after trying yours, plus variants on my full original schema it seems the keyspace create statement was causing the random field and core creation/index errors.  Switching my example to simple strategy like you had `CREATE KEYSPACE wiki WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };` seems to do the trick.